# MCU onboard PID controllers?

Tags: microcontroller, pid-controller

As far as I know, no MCU has an onboard PID controller, with all the frills of timing, PWM (or analog) I/O, filtering etc. Why not? It would certainly seem no more complex than an onboard ADC/DAC

Comment: MCUs (many) have on-board ADCs and, quite a few have on-board DACs too.

Comment: @Andyaka I know, and I use them. But why no full PID implementation on board?

Comment: You originally said it *would certainly seem no more complex than an onboard ADC/DAC* - what else is needed?

Comment: Because this stuff needs to be *highly* customizable. Grab a DSP and have all the power to implement whatever you need yourself.

Comment: Because you can already do it in code. The PWM, analog, ADC, and DAC are hardware. With PWM module to control timing, the PID doesn't need to be cycle perfect.

Comment: @EugeneSh. No more highly customizable that a multiplexed ADC. I do write the same f/w over and over again, and its sucks up MCU cycles. By your argument, why do we bother having PWM outputs when bit bashing would do just as well

Comment: @DirkBruere Perhaps for *your* needs. But what if I need a loop with couple of internal loops? What if I need couple of loops in series? Filter on different places in them? There are many more topologies of control loops than a single simple PID.

Comment: The answer to this sort of question is usually "because the manufacturers don't see enough demand to justify making them".

Comment: My view is that it would not be very *general purpose* any more and would therefore not be quite as popular. It would also add some complexity to offload what is currently done in code / external components to internal hardware. There would have to be no end of tuning parameters. The *capability* is provided by the timers / PWM and so forth, just as the capability of ADCs / DACs and so on is provided.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know, no MCU has an onboard PID controller, with all the frills of timing, PWM (or analog) I/O, filtering etc.

Honestly, I consider many MCUs as *ASICs for control jobs*. An MCU has *all* the things you need to achieve what you describe above, and it's really meant for that:

- timing: hence the timers, and interrupts, and guaranteed latency. In fact, most microcontrollers even have *multiple* timer units.
- PWM: I've never met a microcontroller with > 5 pins that doesn't have PWM hardware?!
- Analog interface/ADC/DAC: many microcontrollers do; they are typically controllable by a timer unit (see first bullet point)
- Filtering (analog): well you need that for your ADC, true, but it really sucks to integrate analog low-speed filtering on silicon dies, and it's super easy to build an RC filter, so that's why it's rarely done. Note that for signal conditioning and space efficiency reasons, some microcontroller do come with a freely usable opamp built in!
- Filtering (digital): That's easy to do in software, and if the CPU designers where smart, not slower than if there was dedicated hardware for it.

Other things you need for PID controllers:

- Differentiation/Integration: same functionality as filters
- bounding/saturation: Yep, many microcontrollers offer saturating math. Because of this.
- Supervision (does it still work? If not, reset / do emergency things): Watchdog units are super common in control-oriented microcontrollers

So, I'm fully not agreeing that an MCU doesn't have onboard specialized units for PID implementation: It looks very much, to me, as if someone took the idea of "industrial PID controller" and made it programmable and versatile, while still trying to be easy to use as PID controller.

> It would certainly seem no more complex than an onboard ADC/DAC

ah, I think you might be wrong here. ADCs can be very well integrated in silicon technology; analog filters cannot. Also, there's the aspect of accuracy and typically also power usage that favor digital loops. Also note that building stable analog filters is much more of a challenge in precision and engineering than handwaving a digital control loop.